# Join invariant violation

Tags: join, apache-pig

I observe a violation of what I think should be a general invariant when I do a join in `pig`.
I would appreciate an explanation of what I am doing - or thinking - wrong.

I have a table (*alias* in `pig` terminology)

```
user_action = distinct (foreach user_action generate action, user);
```

which lists users who engage in certain actions. Note that `distinct` guarantees that `action` and `user` index the alias.

I have another alias which tells me how many times people think about an action:

```
user_thoughts = foreach (group A by (action, user)) generate
  group.action as action, group.user as user, COUNT(A) as tcount;
```

Now I `join` the thoughts with actions:

```
thought_relevance_per_user = foreach (join user_action by (user, action) left,
  user_thought_count by (user, action)) generate
  user_action::user as user, user_action::action as action,
  (user_thoughts::tcount is NULL ? 0L : user_thoughts::tcount) as tcount;
thought_relevance = foreach (group thought_relevance_per_user
  by (action, tcount)) generate
  group.action as action, group.tcount as tcount,
  COUNT(thought_relevance_per_user) as ucount;
```

What I expect is that the number of users engaged in an action computed like this:

```
user_counts = foreach (group user_action by action) generate
  group as action, COUNT(user_action) as ucount;
```

and like this:

```
user_counts = foreach (group thought_relevance by action) generate
  group as action, SUM(thought_relevance::ucount) as ucount;
```

are identical.

They are not - the second one is 10 times as *small* as the first one.

(I do the `user_counts` computation in `R` off line, so the `pig` syntax
above may be wrong).

Why? Is my code wrong? Is my expectation wrong?

Comment: user_action is generated from user_action. user_thoughts[_count] is generated from A. Are those sources different? Probably some small (5-10 lines) test data and a full runnable script would help, not sure though.

Comment: The code seems correct. Have you tried storing the data at various points in the script to see where your expectation breaks down? Is it possible that your R code has an error?

Comment: @Ruslan: how do I create test data in pig? do I have to load it from a file?

Comment: I just meant that you can take a few lines worth input, do you statements and DUMP after each to see what is going on.

Comment: @Ruslan: what does "take a few lines worth input" mean?

Comment: If you put the whole script here, you will have something like: input_data = LOAD 'some_file_path'. Take this 'some_file_path' file, make it small. In you question - provide the contents of it and the desired result of the script.

Answer (score 0):

The code is correct, the reason I am seeing junk is that I `store`ed the aliases before the join and that corrupted them. After I `load` them again, I get the correct behavior.